# Push button momentary 2-pin switch

Tags: switches, circuit-design

I having an issue. I have a basics 2 pin push button switch I bought from a hardware store to power on my 3- 3V mini LED lights.

I use a 9 V battery to power through the switch and I noticed when I keep the switch pressed down for two days (my application project calls for that) it kills my 9v battery dead, which I need the battery to light the LEDs at least one month while staying lit.

So I thought of maybe reversing my project with the same 2 pin switch so when I press the switch down, the light turn off instead on on, hoping to make my 9 V battery last a lot longer maybe longer than one month since the LEDs lights are off now while switch is pressed. THAT WAS WRONG!

Please help me figure out both ways, or if I need a resistor for the regular way of the lights on when switch pressed or I prefer, when switch is pressed, light stay off until switch is released and light come on. It killed my battery 10x faster than the other regular way. I am so confused and I thought it would be easy to just use a 9 V to power 3 - 3 V LED lights, with a push button momentary switch.

Comment: Remove your email address as don't expect anyone to email you with help - this is not that kind of site. I'd suggest you draw a schematic to illustrate what you are wanting to do. My brain nearly explodes trying to figure out your question. 3V mini-lights what are they? 9V battery? A PP3 transistor battery? No surprise it doesn't last long. Remember- we can't see what you're looking at so you need to show us pictures, links etc so we can see and understand what it is you are asking about

Comment: what does battery life have to do with a switch?

Comment: @jsotola sounds like it turned off by shorting the battery...

Comment: There is no difference in normaly close and normaly open switch in power consumption.  The standard 9v battery has capacity 500mAh so if your leds drain 10mA and are connected in series you can expect they will light for a 48hours. So in case you use leds for lighting (not a  low current 2mA signalization leds) the 2 days last seems normal to me.

Comment: It is a good approach is to put some small resistance (like 47 or 100 ohm) in series because the new battery can come with 10V output so after first plug the lights will drain hight current (glow too much) until they discharge to 9V and  waist a lot of capacity during this time, whats a shame.

Comment: The 47 and 100 ohms was calculated for 10mA leds. If you use others you must change this resistance according leds current.

Comment: @Mike Spina - I have deleted your email address from the comment as it is against site policy to do that. HOWEVER you MAY placean email address in your profile and say eg "My email address is in my profile".

Comment: For a battery to last N hours the mattery mAh capacity must be LED_mA x hours. So here is you have 3 LEDs in series and they draw 10 mA for the series string then for 2 months ~= 2 x 30 x 24 ~= 1500 hours you need about 10 mA x 1500 hours = 15000 mAh battery. That's about 4 x the capacity of an AA Alkaline cell and for say 9V you'll need 6+ in series (maybe 8 or 9) so you'd need 4 parallel x 9 series AA = 36 AA batteries!. So a 9V battery is far too low in capacity.

Comment: The difference between the open and closed of the push button momentary switch is one: lights turn on when the button pushed and two: if switched is reversed to not pushing button, led lights stay on…..I figured if I switched the switch or making the open switch ack as closed, the 9v battery would not die fast when led lights are off( not on) but the lights died even faster, with lights off.